# How can I know users is using VS code Insider or not?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I would like to know my extension is running in VS code insider or not

What is the API to return the version of VS code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

console.log(vscode.version) // 1.80.0-insider
```

I found the answer